# create a range limited int or float object or function

Tags: python

What would be the best (loaded term...) to limit the range of an int or a float.

In python they are basically infinite but say I want to "clamp" an int at +-10 and equally cause a wraparound (like in digital) between two arbitrary limit
eg

edit this works

```
 def wrapped(x, L, H):
    return ((x-L) % (H-L))+L
```

Comment: You should start by thinking about how YOU want to implement it. Do you want it to simply drop anything larger? Do you want it to ASSERT if the programmer inserts a larger value? It can vary from a simple assert check to a function.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding this correctly, you could use a mod operator to limit the range between (a,b):

```
def clamped(x, a, b):
  return ((x - a) % b) + a
```

First, normalize `x` to be around `0`, then mod by `b`, then restore the modded value back to the start.

Then, wrap-around would also work!

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see the wraparound part. Good answer!

Comment: ahhhhh, I was actually trying with a function an pretty much had what you got but ahd the + and the - the wrong way round...  I am basically trying to mimic a digital system (some integration, cordic etc...) so  I am not sure whether it should be via a class or via a final clamp/wrap function. Thanks though

Comment: wait no ... issues with that: clamped(10,11,20) returns 30

Comment: That's because b is the range, not the upper limit. 30<11+20.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a simple class and have it wrap around using `%` when you tried to assign a value higher than your range.

```
class NewInt:
    def __init__(self, value=0, range=10):
        self.value = value
        self.range = range

    def set(self, number):
        self.value = number % self.range

    def get(self):            # just in case you don't want to call to obj.value
        return self.value
```

Answer (score 1):

A more natural class implementation.

```
class IntOverflow(Exception):
    pass


class LimitedInt(object):
    def __init__(self, value, range):
        self._value = value
        self._range = range

    def __add__(self, some_int):
        return abs(self._value + some_int) <= self._range and (self._value + some_int) or self._error()

    @staticmethod
    def _error():
        raise IntOverflow

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._value)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._value)


a = LimitedInt(3, 10)
print(a + 3)
print(a + 10)
```

Output

```
6
...IntOverflow...
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this could be done. Compared to my answer, yours is better for implementation.